# Remove disabled class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery function to add disabled class onclick, it is working fine. But I want to remove the class by clicking on other button, that is not working can anyone help me with this? This is code...

```js
//Delay add disabled class on cart
$('.fa-shopping-cart').on('click',function(){
 var $this = $(this).addClass('finsihed');
 window.setTimeout(function(){
     $this.addClass('disabled-button');
 }, 1500); //<-- Delay in milliseconds
}); 


function reEnableBtn(prodId) {
   alert(prodId);
//   var $this = $(this).removeClass('finsihed');
// window.setTimeout(function(){
//     $this.removeClass('disabled-button');
// }, 1500); //<-- Delay in milliseconds
    $('.festi-cart-remove-product').removeClass('disabled-button');
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart finsihed disabled-button"></i>
   
<a href="#" onclick="reEnableBtn()">Re-enable button</a>
```

I hope you guys understand my question..

Comment: Pretty sure you should correct that `finsihed`

Comment: You do not have this class: `'.festi-cart-remove-product'` on your button.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `reEnableBtn`, `$('.festi-cart-remove-product')` doesn't exist.

Change :

```
 $('.festi-cart-remove-product').removeClass('disabled-button');
```

To :

```
$('.fa-shopping-cart').removeClass('disabled-button');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I came to understand your question, please check given link or snippet if this is what you want...

```js
var $this = '#cart';
  $(document).on('click','#blockr,'+$this,function(){
    $($this).addClass('disabled');
  })

  $(document).on('click','#openr',function(){
    $('#cart').removeClass('disabled');
})
```

```css
.disabled{
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.7.0" data-semver="4.7.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="cart">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart finsihed disabled-button"></i>
    </button>
    <br /> <br />
    <a class="btn btn-default" id="blockr" href="#!">Disabled button</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" id="openr" href="#!">Re-enable button</a>
    
  
  </body>

</html>
```

link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3m9mKo8EQkGnjpqs54U6?p=preview

or you can comment if you want something modified in it. Hope it helps you.